# mixing a project in ProTools with automation is it possible to suspend the automation during playback as if it was automated turned on/off

Tags: mixing, pro-tools

I'm trying to save DSP on my computer and my current mix session has alot of tracks with automation. Is there any way to set the plugins through automation to suspend during playback on and off?

Answer (score 2):

I think all ProTools plugins have a master bypass that you can automate to bypass the plugin.  I don't know that it really saves power though.
ProTools 11 has dynamic plugin allocation so the plugs that aren't processing aren't taking up power.
Other options might be thinning the automation more or increasing your playback buffer size.

Comment: you'd have to deactivate the plugin, something i'm not aware of to be automate able.. if you really want to save dsp, reorganise your routing to a more minimalistic style. otherwise you'll simply end up hitting the cpu max...

Answer (score 2):

If you hit cmd and 4 on the neumeric keypad (ctrl 4 on PC) or go to Window>Automation the automation window will pop up. From there just hit the 'Suspend' button at the top and all automation in the session will be suspended.